# Local storage variable

Tags: solidity, state-variable, documentation, local-variables, memory-pointer

I am reading the solidity docs [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#data-location) and I seem to be struggling to understand the 
 following.

> Data locations are important because they change how assignments
>   behave:  assignments between storage and memory and also to a state
>   variable (even  from other state variables) always create an
>   independent copy. Assignments  to local storage variables only assign
>   a reference though, and this  reference always points to the state
>   variable even if the latter is changed  in the meantime. On the other
>   hand, assignments from a memory stored  reference type to another
>   memory-stored reference type do not create a copy

1)Isn't a state variable always stored in the storage? So what does the above mean by assignments between storage and memory and also to a state variable?

2) What exactly is a local storage variable?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract C {

    uint state_variable; // same as global storage variable

    function test() returns uint{
        uint local_variable = 10; //same as local storage variable
        return local_variable * state_variable;
    }
}
```

Is my understanding above correct? Is there a way to see if these variables are in memory or storage , I am looking at the disassembled op codes in remix IDE but unable to make it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value assignment to a variable can be done by either giving a reference or creating an independent copy. If it's a reference when the original one which is assigned to the variable get changed value of the variable also gets changed.
Consider the following,

```
a = 10 // value of a is 10
b = a // variable b is assigned a value
a = 20
```

if the assignment above assigned a reference now the value of b will also be 20. If the assignment was done by creating an independent copy value of b will be still 10.

In the solidity doc what it says is if the assignment is between the storage and memory,or the assignment is to a state variable it will always create an independent copy. If it's a local storage variable it will only make a reference.

Referring to the example provided in the solidity docs, local storage variable is a variable defined inside a function. (The scope of the variable is limited to the function)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the accepted answer, I think it's needed to identify what data locations are as well.

Documentation provides a good description on available [data locations](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/types.html#data-location).

> **Data location**
>
> Every reference type has an additional annotation, the “data
> location”, about where it is stored. There are three data locations:
> `memory`, `storage` and `calldata`. Calldata is a non-modifiable,
> non-persistent area where function arguments are stored, and behaves
> mostly like memory. It is required for parameters of external
> functions but can also be used for other variables.